# Why did this TSP code fail in the case mentioned but worked else where?

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm

I am implementing Travelling Salesman Problem with Dynamic approach. I have added my attempt below. The code compiled and gave correct output for most of the cases. However, it failed when I had matrix representation: [[0,10,1],[1,0,10],[10,1,0]]. I expect the result to be 3 but it is showing me 30 as the output.

I have done recursion calls and dict map stores the keys for memorization.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int v;
int G[10][10];
int parent[10];
map<pair<int,set<int> >, int > dict;
void solve(int,set<int>);
int tsp(int,set<int>);

int main(){
    set<int> s,s_o;
    set<int>::iterator it;
    cout<<"Give number of vertices"<<endl;
    cin>>v;
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
        s.insert(i);
    //cout<<"Give number of edges"<<endl;
    //cin>>e;
    s_o=s;
    cout<<"Give edges"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<v;j++){
            cin>>G[i][j];
        }
    }
    solve(0,s);
    return 0;
}

void solve(int i,set<int> s){
    parent[i]=-1;
    set<int>::iterator it;
    it=s.find(i);
    s.erase(it);
    // for(it=s.begin();it!=s.end();++it)
    //   cout<<*it<<" ";
    int ans=tsp(0,s);
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
        cout<<parent[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

int tsp(int a,set<int>s){
    set<int>::iterator it;
    int min_cost=1000000;
    int k,min_k;
    if(s.empty()){
        return G[a][0];
    }
    for(it=s.begin();it!=s.end();++it){
        k=*it;
        s.erase(it);
        if(dict.find(pair<int, set<int> >(k,s))!=dict.end()){
            //cout<<"here"<<endl;
            return G[a][k]+ dict.at(pair<int, set<int> >(k,s));
        }
        else{
            if(tsp(k,s)<min_cost){
                min_cost=tsp(k,s);
                min_k=k;
            }
            pair<int,set<int> > x(k,s);
            dict.insert(pair<pair<int, set<int> >,int >(x,min_cost));
            parent[a]=min_k; //i must admit that this is accidental, but 
            //it worked xD
            return G[a][k]+min_cost;
        }
    }
}
```

Also the parent array I expect to hold parent of vertex and -1 for source(0 in case). 
Is there anything wrong in the tsp() function? If not, why did it give answer as 30?
Also, what is wrong in the parent array use?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: You have undefined behavoir. Once you call `s.erase(it);` then you can no-longer use `it` yet you continue using `it` as part of the for loop.

Comment: Can you please specify where?

Comment: in `tsp` you do `s.erase(it)`. This removes the element it is referencing and so it is no longer valid to access `it` in any way after that. Yet when the loop gets back to the top it does `++it` and `it != blah` of which neither are allowed as `it` no longer references a valid item.

Comment: See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) which mentions `set::erase` does: _References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected._

Comment: then how should i delete the elements 1 by 1 and pass the reduced set to tsp?